# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module using material ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm pretty new in material UI. I have react project and I'm using material UI in it. I want to use customized radio button according to Mui document: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-radio-button/#customization. I used it like the document does, but when I used custom radio tag in formControlLabel (<FormControlLabel value="female" control={} label="Female" />
), I received this error in the browser :

> SyntaxError:
> 1 of 1 unhandled error
> Server Error:Cannot use import statement outside a module

These are my custom styles:

```
export const BpIcon =styled('span')(({theme})=>({
  borderRadius: '50%',
  width: 16,
  height: 16,
  boxShadow:
    theme.palette.mode === 'dark'
      ? '0 0 0 1px rgb(16 22 26 / 40%)'
      : 'inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(16,22,26,.2), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(16,22,26,.1)',
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#394b59' : '#f5f8fa',
  backgroundImage:
    theme.palette.mode === 'dark'
      ? 'linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.05),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))'
      : 'linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.8),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))',
  '.Mui-focusVisible &': {
    outline: '2px auto rgba(19,124,189,.6)',
    outlineOffset: 2,
  },
  'input:hover ~ &': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#30404d' : '#ebf1f5',
  },
  'input:disabled ~ &': {
    boxShadow: 'none',
    background:
      theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'rgba(57,75,89,.5)' : 'rgba(206,217,224,.5)',
  },
}))

export const BpCheckedIcon  = styled(BpIcon)({
  backgroundColor: '#137cbd',
  backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))',
  '&:before': {
    display: 'block',
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    backgroundImage: 'radial-gradient(#fff,#fff 28%,transparent 32%)',
    content: '""',
  },
  'input:hover ~ &': {
    backgroundColor: '#106ba3',
  },
});
```

And this is my component:

```
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@mui/material/FormLabel';
import Radio from '@mui/material/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@mui/material/RadioGroup';
import { BpCheckedIcon,BpIcon } from '../../mui';
export const BpRadio=()=>{
  return (
   
    <Radio
    disableRipple
    color="default"
    checkedIcon={<BpCheckedIcon  />}
    icon={<BpIcon  />}
   
  />

  )
}

export default function AddPostModal(){
return(
<>
    <FormControl>
  <FormLabel id="demo-radio-buttons-group-label">Gender</FormLabel>
  <RadioGroup
    aria-labelledby="demo-radio-buttons-group-label"
    defaultValue="female"
    name="radio-buttons-group"
  >
 
    <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<BpRadio  />} label="Female" />
    <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<BpRadio  />} label="Male" />
    <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<BpRadio  />} label="Other" />
  </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
</>
)
}
```

When I remove these three Lines of code(     `<FormControlLabel value="female" control={<BpRadio  />} label="Female" /> <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<BpRadio  />} label="Male" /> <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<BpRadio  />} label="Other" />`),The app works perfectly and when I use BpRadio as an isolated component (not in the control just using  inside ), I never see this error. So I think the problem is related to using one custom component in control of another component.

Comment: But it working perfectly in demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-tesla-6630dk?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: @AmrEraky Tnx. Yes it works in sandbox and doesn't work in my local machine. I Thought that's related to typescript config or something but I haven't find the bug yet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved it. The problem was that I used extra path, importing FormControlLabel. I changed this:

```
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel/FormControlLabel';
```

to this:

```
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel
```

And it worked!